# Finding the dimesion of the subspace $P_3$.

Tags: linear-algebra

In each of the following find the dimension of the subspace of $P_3$ spanned by the given vectors.

$(a)\quad x,x-1,x^2+1$

$(b)\quad x,x-1,x^2+1,x^2-1$

---

**Dimension** is the number of vectors in any basis for the space to be spanned.

**Rank** of a matrix is the dimension of the column space

$(A)$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & -1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} =^{rref} \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$$

My questions is does this matrix have a dimension of $3$ and rank $3$. Or a Rank $2$ with dimension $2$?

$(B)$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1&1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 &0\\
        0 & -1 & 1&-1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} =^{rref} \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0&-2 \\
        0 & 1 & 0&2 \\
        0 & 0 & 1&1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$$

My question remains the same, I think this matrix has a dimension of $3$ and a rank of $3$. However, I am not too confident that this is correct.The number of pivots decides the dimension. I just need some confirmation that my work is correct.

Comment: what does the word 'rref' means?

Comment: Presumably reduced row echelon form

Comment: @flytothesurface yes